# Comparing a new dataframe to an old dataframe when dealing with dataframes as a timeseries?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe, last_bid_vol_price, being updated repeatedly.

```
import ccxt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


binanceus = ccxt.binanceus({
    'enableRateLimit': True,
})
last_bid_vol_price = pd.DataFrame()
while True:
    #organize the LOB data the way I want it
    orderbook = binanceus.fetch_order_book('BTC/USD')
    orderbook_df = pd.DataFrame(orderbook)
    orderbook_df.drop(["timestamp", "datetime", 'nonce'],axis=1,inplace=True)
    #split bids list
    asks = orderbook_df.asks.apply(pd.Series)
    #split asks list and merge the two lists
    order = orderbook_df.bids.apply(pd.Series).merge(asks, left_index = True, right_index = True)
    #back to df
    orderbook_df = pd.DataFrame(order)
    #rename headers
    orderbook_df.columns = ['bids', 'bids_volume', 'asks', 'asks_volume']

    #extract the bids where volume is over 1 BTC
    bid_vol_price = orderbook_df['bids'].where(orderbook_df['bids_volume'] > 1)
    bid_vol = orderbook_df['bids_volume'].where(orderbook_df['bids_volume'] > 1)
    bid_vol_price.dropna(inplace=True)
    bid_vol.dropna(inplace=True)
    bid_vol_price = pd.concat([bid_vol_price, bid_vol], axis=1)
    bid_vol_price = bid_vol_price.assign(count=0)

    #check if first run
    if last_bid_vol_price.empty == True:
        last_bid_vol_price = bid_vol_price

    #count how many times the bid has remained on the orderbook
    mask = ((last_bid_vol_price['bids'] == bid_vol_price['bids'])
            and (last_bid_vol_price['bids_volume'] == bid_vol_price['bids_volume']))
    bid_vol_price['count'] = bid_vol_price['count'].mask(mask, bid_vol_price['count'] + 1)

    #update last_bid_volume_price for the next go by keeping the new volume rows and droping the
    #rows that don't exist and dropping the rows with the previous counts
    last_bid_vol_price = pd.merge(last_bid_vol_price, bid_vol_price, on=['bids', 'bids_volume'], how='right')


    print(last_bid_vol_price)
```

I'm looking to achieve an out put like this. Not exact data but style.

```
      bids  bids_volume  count
0  6738.23     1.634321      1
1  6733.82     1.607452      1
2  6694.20     9.981800      1
```

I would like to take the `bid_vol_price` store it in a variable `last_bid_vol_price` and compare it to the new `bid_vol_price` that comes in and eventually count the rows with duplicate values but also remove the row(s) in the `last_bid_vol_price` that does not exist with in the new `bid_vol_price`.

The problem I'm having to begin with is comparing the two dataframes because the row's index and the dataframe's size can change at any moment. Help with comparing the change in these two dataframes would be appreciated.

I need to make sure that `last_bid_vol_price` `bids` and `bids_volume` column's row matches `bid_vol_price`'s even though the row's index can change and there could be more or less rows.

With

```
mask = ((last_bid_vol_price['bids'] == bid_vol_price['bids'])
            and (last_bid_vol_price['bids_volume'] == 
            bid_vol_price['bids_volume']))
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

With

```
mask = (last_bid_vol_price['bids'] == bid_vol_price['bids'])
```

I get it to loop till `bid_vol_price` changes and then I get this error:

```
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

I can't use this `mask` without the `bids_volume` matching as well. It is possible for someone to cancel a bid and a new bid arrives on the orderbook with different volume. If that happened the count will be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After 4 days I figured it out.

```
import ccxt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


binanceus = ccxt.binanceus({
    'enableRateLimit': True,
})
last_bid_vol_price = pd.DataFrame()
while True:
    #organize the LOB data the way I want it
    orderbook = binanceus.fetch_order_book('BTC/USD')
    orderbook_df = pd.DataFrame(orderbook)
    orderbook_df.drop(["timestamp", "datetime", 'nonce'],axis=1,inplace=True)
    #split bids list
    asks = orderbook_df.asks.apply(pd.Series)
    #split asks list and merge the two lists
    order = orderbook_df.bids.apply(pd.Series).merge(asks, left_index = True, right_index = True)
    #back to df
    orderbook_df = pd.DataFrame(order)
    #rename headers
    orderbook_df.columns = ['bids', 'bids_volume', 'asks', 'asks_volume']

    #extract the bids where volume is over 1 BTC
    bid_vol_price = orderbook_df['bids'].where(orderbook_df['bids_volume'] > 1)
    bid_vol = orderbook_df['bids_volume'].where(orderbook_df['bids_volume'] > 1)
    bid_vol_price.dropna(inplace=True)
    bid_vol.dropna(inplace=True)
    bid_vol_price = pd.concat([bid_vol_price, bid_vol], axis=1)
    bid_vol_price = bid_vol_price.assign(count=0.0)

    #check if first run
    if last_bid_vol_price.empty == True:
        last_bid_vol_price = bid_vol_price
```

The following code solves my problem with the added benefit of keeping the index of where the bids are placed.

```
    #update last_bid_volume_price for the next go by keeping the new volume rows and droping the
    #rows that no longer exist and while updating the counts of rows that continue to exist
    bid_vol_price_m = pd.merge(bid_vol_price, last_bid_vol_price, on=['bids','bids_volume'], how='left', indicator='exist')
    #count_y, count_x column's is produced from the merge above 
    bid_vol_price_m['count'] = np.where(bid_vol_price_m.exist =='both', bid_vol_price_m['count_y'] + 1, 0)
    bid_vol_price_m = bid_vol_price_m.drop(['exist', 'count_x', 'count_y'], axis=1)
    #keep the index values and order from bid_vol_price
    bid_vol_price_m.index = bid_vol_price.index
    last_bid_vol_price = bid_vol_price_m
    print(last_bid_vol_price)
```

Here's some output

```
15  6670.97     2.558446   15.0
29  6658.99     1.020400   15.0
42  6650.00     3.052699   15.0
47  6643.85     9.780500   15.0
94  6608.07     2.968100   15.0
       bids  bids_volume  count
15  6670.97     2.558446   16.0
29  6658.99     1.020400   16.0
42  6650.00     3.052699   16.0
47  6643.85     9.780500   16.0
94  6608.07     2.968100   16.0
       bids  bids_volume  count
8   6678.92     2.225173    0.0
16  6670.97     2.558446   17.0
30  6658.99     1.020400   17.0
43  6650.00     3.052699   17.0
48  6643.85     9.780500   17.0
95  6608.07     2.968100   17.0
       bids  bids_volume  count
8   6678.92     2.225173    1.0
16  6670.97     2.558446   18.0
30  6658.99     1.020400   18.0
43  6650.00     3.052699   18.0
48  6643.85     9.780500   18.0
95  6608.07     2.968100   18.0
       bids  bids_volume  count
15  6670.97     2.558446   19.0
29  6658.99     1.020400   19.0
42  6650.00     3.052699   19.0
47  6643.85     9.780500   19.0
94  6608.07     2.968100   19.0
```

I hope this helps someone.